# pandas columns in loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a problem with iterating through pandas column names. Could someone please help me figure out how to perform this loop?

```
lista = list()

lista.append(('col1',clear[clear.col1 > lock.col1.max()].shape[0]))
lista.append(('col2',clear[clear.col2 > lock.col2.max()].shape[0]))
lista.append(('col3',clear[clear.col3 > lock.col3.max()].shape[0]))
```

what I'm trying to do:
clear and lock have the same columns
I want to take maximum value of one dataframe column and subset other dataframe by this value (take from shape number of rows)

Could please someone explain me what I'm doing here wrong?
when trying to this in loop getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'I'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method of addressing columns:

```py
lista.append(('col1',clear[clear['col1'] > lock['col1'].max()].shape[0]))
```